# About upgrading magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.7, upgrade, magento-1.8

I'm currently using Magento CE 1.7 for my shop and I would like to upgrade to Magento CE 1.8.

I would like to know if I can run to issues upgrading with the 3th party extensions I'm using and any core code modifications I've made. In short I'd like to know what I can expect when I upgrade the installation.

Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you're getting a few downvotes I'd suggest expanding on your question. Maybe mention some modifications you've made on your store and what the main concerns are. You're question is a valid concern so please edit it :)

Comment: I would also suggest waiting for Magento CE 1.8.1 - It will include many updates and bug fixes that are not in 1.8.0

Comment: You can run into upgrade issues on any Magento upgrade, even the seemingly minor ones. Do it on a test server so you don't inconvenience your customers, hammer it hard and find out what third party modules can't handle it. And as @brentwpeterson states, it's not a bad idea to let them filter the dross out of RTM Gold. The patches on the first update are often quite important.

Comment: I hope you did not edited the core code directly, you should only add your overwriting code into /local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short answer: **yes**

long answer: it completely depends on what extensions you are using, the modifications you've made to templates or code. If you've overwritten core files (Moving a file to `app/code/local/Mage/...` and modifying the code) etc etc.

Best approach in your case would be to make a copy of the store locally, do the upgrade and see what happens. My guess is there will be a few issues that you can then go about fixing.

Once you have your test environment running perfectly you can either copy it to your live environment or do the modifications you did on test again on live.

Comment: Thanks. Do you now what are the new improvements added relative to the version 1.7 ?

Comment: If you google on "Magento 1.8 release" you'll find the Magento blog http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/magento-community-edition-one-eight-now-available/ and the release notes http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-later-release-notes?icid=BLOG_magentoce18release_knowledgebase

Comment: Hey @Amirov can I help you with anything else? If not, please close the question to keep the answer rate up :)

Comment: great, if you run into trouble while upgrading later on, you know where to post the questions!